# cannot retrieve branches,check if the provided repository location is vaid

Tags: github, zend-studio, egit

When I use zend studio to create a project from github, I get the following error message:

> Cannot retrieve branches, check if the provided repository location is valid

[image]

Can anyone explain how to solve this?

Comment: And what location did you provide?

Comment: Same error here...it makes no sense.  I think the plugin is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted that this would have been fixed in Zend Studio update in June 2013, but I didn't get it to work by installing the update...

However, I got it to work by choosing 1) Import Git -> Projects from Git 2) Import as General Project 3) right clicking from the PHP Explorer -> Configure -> Add PHP Support .